# Does Ciel Phantomhive ever kill anyone?

Tags: black-butler

Whether it's direct (with his own hands) or indirect (orders Sebastian to do it), does Ciel ever kill anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ciel never killed someone using his own hands. However, he ordered Sebastian to kill people several times. There are also times where Sebastian killed people indirectly from Ciel's orders, like when Ciel ordered Sebastian to save him in the early episodes (episode 3 & 4 if I'm not mistaken) of the anime. Below are some of the occasions where Ciel directly ordered Sebastian to kill people.

In the Book of Circus, Ciel ordered Sebastian to burn down the mansion and killing the criminals and the innocent children inside.

When the Queen of England shows herself as a modified human and that her adjutant is actually the angel, Ciel ordered Sebastian to kill them.

Comment: To add a bit more context in the manga Ciel did in fact shoot the owner of the circus several times before ordering Sebastian to kill them. Also in the emerald witch arc he shot several zombies but they were *technically* already dead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ciel has killed someone.

He killed

> Baron Kelvin in season 3 episode 8

with his gun.

> Kelvin was still alive, so Ciel kicked him and was about to shoot again just Joker stopped him. But he died from blood loss, so Ciel did kill someone.